# React native how to add a secondary color to a circular border

Tags: react-native

I have something like this.

```
<View style={styles.chart}>
    <Text>{props.unScannedCartons && calculateTotalProgress()}%</Text>
</View>
```

My style for "styles.chart" is

```
  chart: {
    width: 48,
    height: 48,

    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",

    borderRadius: 48,
    borderWidth: 4,
    borderColor: Color.opacity(Theme.colors.ink, 0.16),
  },
```

This creates [image]

However let's say I want 25% or 30% of the border color to be red, while the rest of the border stays black. How can I achieve this without a third party package?

Comment: either with an SVG or manually by wrapping your component in another View with its own border.

Comment: Care to show an example? I've tried wrapping it but was rendering properly on ios but not android. I used this reference. https://medium.com/@0saurabhgour/react-native-percentage-based-progress-circle-no-external-library-e25b43e83888
Here is the snack:
https://snack.expo.dev/A6WTEXbyf?platform=android

Working on ios but not android. Trying to understand why that is.

Comment: I misread the post - if you are doing a progress circle SVG is the easiest way.  here's an example https://github.com/bartgryszko/react-native-circular-progress/blob/master/src/CircularProgress.js

Answer (score 0):

You can use a masked view [@react-native-masked-view/masked-view](https://github.com/react-native-masked-view/masked-view)

Here is an [example](https://snack.expo.dev/@m.bahl/masked-view-animated) (based on this [post](https://blog.logrocket.com/creating-visuals-react-native-masked-view/))

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  StyleSheet,
  TextInput,
  View,
  Button,
  Animated,
  Easing,
} from 'react-native';
import MaskedView from '@react-native-masked-view/masked-view';
import heartImage from './assets/heart.png';

function App() {
  const openerAnim = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;
  const [animDone, setAnimDone] = useState(false);

  const appOpacity = {
    opacity: openerAnim.interpolate({
      inputRange: [0, 15, 30],
      outputRange: [0, 0, 1],
      extrapolate: 'clamp',
    }),
  };

  const appScale = {
    transform: [
      {
        scale: openerAnim.interpolate({
          inputRange: [0, 100],
          outputRange: [1.1, 1]
        }),
      },
    ],
  };

  const maskScale = {
    transform: [
      {
        scale: openerAnim.interpolate({
          inputRange: [0, 10, 100],
          outputRange: [1, 0.8, 70],
        }),
      },
    ],
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    Animated.timing(
      openerAnim,
      {
        toValue: 100,
        duration: 2000,
        easing: Easing.cubic,
        useNativeDriver: true
      }
    ).start(() => {
      setAnimDone(true);
    });
  }, []);


  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      { !animDone ? <View style={[StyleSheet.absoluteFill, styles.backgroundFillBlue]}></View> : null }
      <MaskedView
        style={styles.maskedView}
        maskElement={
          <View style={styles.maskWrapper}>
            <Animated.Image source={heartImage}
              style={[styles.mask, maskScale]}/>
          </View>
        }>
        { !animDone ? <View style={[StyleSheet.absoluteFill, styles.backgroundFillWhite]}></View> : null }
        <Animated.View style={[styles.loginBox, appScale, appOpacity]}>
          <TextInput
            value=""
            placeholder="Username"
            placeholderTextColor="#666"
            style={styles.input}
          />
          <TextInput
            value=""
            placeholder="Password"
            placeholderTextColor="#666"
            secureTextEntry={true}
            style={styles.input}
          />
          <View style={styles.separator}/>
          <Button title="Login"/>
        </Animated.View>
      </MaskedView>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#ff00fff'
  },
  maskedView: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  maskWrapper: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  mask: {
    width: 150,
    height: 150,
  },
  loginBox: {
    flex: 1,
    height: '100%',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#eee',
    padding: 40
  },
  backgroundFillBlue: {
    backgroundColor: '#0091ff',
  },
  backgroundFillWhite: {
    backgroundColor: 'white',
  },
  input: {
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: '#aaa',
    borderRadius: 4,
    padding: 12,
    marginBottom: 12,
  },
  separator: {
    height: 20
  }
});

export default App;
```

Maybe you should consider using a library like [SKIA](https://github.com/Shopify/react-native-skia)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did to create a simple circular progress:

```
type CircularProgressProps = {
  progressPercent: number;
  style?: ViewStyle;
  backgroundCircleColor?: string;
  progressCircleColor?: string;
};

const CircularProgress = ({
  progressPercent,
  style,
  backgroundCircleColor = Color.opacity(Theme.colors.ink, 0.16),
  progressCircleColor = Theme.colors.positive,
}: CircularProgressProps) => {
  const radius = (48 - 4) / 2;
  const circum = radius * 2 * Math.PI;
  const svgProgress = 100 - progressPercent;
  const circleSize = 48 / 2;

  return (
    <View style={style}>
      <Svg width={48} height={48}>
        <Circle
          stroke={backgroundCircleColor}
          fill="none"
          cx={circleSize}
          cy={circleSize}
          r={radius}
          strokeWidth={4}
        />
        <Circle
          stroke={progressCircleColor}
          fill="none"
          cx={circleSize}
          cy={circleSize}
          r={radius}
          strokeDasharray={progressPercent === 0 ? `${0.01} ${circum}` : `${circum} ${circum}`}
          strokeDashoffset={radius * Math.PI * 2 * (svgProgress / 100)}
          strokeLinecap="round"
          transform={`rotate(-90, ${circleSize}, ${circleSize})`}
          strokeWidth={4}
        />
        <SVGText
          fontSize={Theme.fonts.fontSize.xs}
          x={circleSize}
          y={circleSize + (Theme.fonts.fontSize.xs / 2 - 1)}
          textAnchor="middle"
          fill={Color.secondary(Theme.colors.ink)}
          fontWeight={Theme.fonts.fontWeight.bold}
        >
          {`${progressPercent}%`}
        </SVGText>
      </Svg>
    </View>
  );
};

export { CircularProgress };
```